# r.js optimizer resolving configured deps files

Tags: requirejs, optimization

I try requireJS optimizer to pack all my scripts into one file and I cannot overcome one issue.

My *requireJs* configuration is

```
var require = {
    //    'baseUrl': 'static/scripts',
    'paths': {
        'external': 'global/external'
    },
    'waitSeconds': 2,
    //    'enforceDefine': true,
    'deps': ['external/jquery-1.7.2'],
    'config': {

    }
};
```

*requireJs* will load everything that is in deps before it starts loading any other scripts. since jquery wraps itself with define function and with name jquery I can load it to my scripts simply by calling

```
var var $ = require('jquery');
```

This works great when code is not optimized.

PROBLEM:
when I run r.js (with node - but this I think is irrelevant) optimizer prints error that it cannot resolve jquery dependency. 
There is nothing in *requireJs* optimizer faq on that. I tried play with configuring 'path' property but it didnt fix anything.

Answer (score 1):

I removed deps property and added new element to paths

```
var require = {
    //    'baseUrl': 'static/scripts',
    'paths': {
        'external': 'global/external'
        'jquery': 'global/external/jquery-1.7.2'
    },
    'waitSeconds': 2,
...
};
```

it didnt play before because I tried to setup path to jquery like

```
'jquery': 'external/jquery-1.7.2'
```

thinking that external should evaluate to

```
'global/external/jquery-1.7.2'
```

then I just set path.jquery in build script (or as argument to r.js) once again and it worked